# ASP.NET Core web API solution space filled with many files after changing xml output path

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using Swagger to do my API documentation, when trying to write the XML comments i changed the options/build file path to be 'apiNameAPI.xml' instead of the loacal path. After doing that many many files suddenly appeared in my solution space.
[image]

This definitely wasn't supposed to happen, and worst of all, it still cant find my path to write the comments.

Any ideas on how to revert this? And to et the XML comments working.

EDIT: add .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>ParkyAPI.XML</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>ParkyAPI.XML</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Data\Migrations\" />
    <Folder Include="Repository\" />
    <Folder Include="Repository\IRepository\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\Dtos\" />
    <Folder Include="ParkyMapper\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.8">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I am running on macOS with VS2019

Comment: Can you show the csproj?

Comment: have edited. Really have no idea why all these other files showed up.

Answer (score 0):

From [Common MSBuild Project Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties). `OutputPath` is to

> Specifies the path to the output directory, relative to the project directory, for example, bin\Debug.

This property wait a directory, but you set xml file.

If you want enable xml doc, the easy way is to edit csproj and enable the property `GenerateDocumentationFile`. (By Visual Studio, this generate all this condition to be compatible with legacy csproj format).

In your case, replace

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>ParkyAPI.XML</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>ParkyAPI.XML</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

By

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After, you can load the xml doc in swagger with :

```cs
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationName + ".xml");
    if (File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
    {
        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlFilePath);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not being given access to the path for my xml file now. I get a CS0016 error " Access to the path '/Users/xxxx/Projects/RESTfulAPI1/Parky/ParkyAPI/ParkyAPI.xml' is denied."

Comment: Close Visual Studio, clean you project directory and retry